# Laravel 5: how do I tell Sessions.php to use my .env database connection?

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like sessions to be saved to database.

in `Sessions.php` I specified:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

The connection section is null though by default...

```
'connection' => null,
```

I'd like for it to use the information in my `.env` file to gain database connection. How do I do that?

The reason I'm asking is because with that connection as 'null' - it doesn't write anything to my database (and other parts of my app do, so I know the database connection is ok). I created the sessions table as the documentation says - but still nothing is ever written there.

Comment: Take a look at: http://laravel.io/forum/04-29-2014-session-persistence-with-database-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out. My `.env` file had `SESSION_DRIVER` as `file`. Somehow I missed that. Changing it to `database` resolved this and now the sessions are written to my database correctly.